# Does the port numbers needs to be changed when changing from leveldb to couchdb in Hyperledger-Fabric

Tags: docker, docker-compose, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm working on the frontend of a blockchain app using Hyperledger 1.1 and [Chainhero SDK](https://chainhero.io/2018/06/tutorial-build-blockchain-app-v1-1-0/). After changing Hyperledger version from 1.4 to 1.1 (because of missing support of 1.4 from SDK) and changing the default database from levelDb to couchDb it will not initialize. Do you need to change ports when converting from levelDb to couchDb?

I have been working on a chaincode in Hyperledger (HL). I finished developing my back-end with the chaincode and is now working on front-end where I use the Chainhero SDK. Since this SDK is only supporting HL 1.1 I needed to change HL version. After this I forgot updating the version control, and now the network will not boot and comes with the following error output: 
`Unable to initialize the Fabric SDK: failed to make admin join channel: join channel failed: SendProposal failed: Transaction processing for endorser [localhost:7051]: Endorser Client Status Code: (2) CONNECTION_FAILED. Description: dialing connection timed out [localhost:7051]`

When changing from levelDb to couchDb I followed [this guide](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html#using-couchdb). Which doesn't state anything about changing ports.

I expected it to initialize, but there seems to be a problem. And I not sure if it would help to increase the time, or it's a problem with the ports?

config.yaml

```
name: "heroes-service-network"
#
# Schema version of the content. Used by the SDK to apply the corresponding parsing rules.
#
version: 1.0.0

#
# The client section used by GO SDK.
#
client:

  # Which organization does this application instance belong to? The value must be the name of an org
  # defined under "organizations"
  organization: org1

  logging:
    level: info

  # Global configuration for peer, event service and orderer timeouts
  # if this this section is omitted, then default values will be used (same values as below)
#  peer:
#    timeout:
#      connection: 10s
#      response: 180s
#      discovery:
#        # Expiry period for discovery service greylist filter
#        # The channel client will greylist peers that are found to be offline
#        # to prevent re-selecting them in subsequent retries.
#        # This interval will define how long a peer is greylisted
#        greylistExpiry: 10s
#  eventService:
#    # Event service type (optional). If not specified then the type is automatically
#    # determined from channel capabilities.
#    type: (deliver|eventhub)
    # the below timeouts are commented out to use the default values that are found in
    # "pkg/fab/endpointconfig.go"
    # the client is free to override the default values by uncommenting and resetting
    # the values as they see fit in their config file
#    timeout:
#      connection: 15s
#      registrationResponse: 15s
#  orderer:
#    timeout:
#      connection: 15s
#      response: 15s
#  global:
#    timeout:
#      query: 180s
#      execute: 180s
#      resmgmt: 180s
#    cache:
#      connectionIdle: 30s
#      eventServiceIdle: 2m
#      channelConfig: 30m
#      channelMembership: 30s
#      discovery: 10s
#      selection: 10m

  # Root of the MSP directories with keys and certs.
  cryptoconfig:
    path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/chainHero/heroes-service/fixtures/crypto-config

  # Some SDKs support pluggable KV stores, the properties under "credentialStore"
  # are implementation specific
  credentialStore:
    path: /tmp/heroes-service-store

    # [Optional]. Specific to the CryptoSuite implementation used by GO SDK. Software-based implementations
    # requiring a key store. PKCS#11 based implementations does not.
    cryptoStore:
      path: /tmp/heroes-service-msp

   # BCCSP config for the client. Used by GO SDK.
  BCCSP:
    security:
     enabled: true
     default:
      provider: "SW"
     hashAlgorithm: "SHA2"
     softVerify: true
     level: 256

  tlsCerts:
    # [Optional]. Use system certificate pool when connecting to peers, orderers (for negotiating TLS) Default: false
    systemCertPool: false

    # [Optional]. Client key and cert for TLS handshake with peers and orderers
    client:
      keyfile:
      certfile:

#
# [Optional]. But most apps would have this section so that channel objects can be constructed
# based on the content below. If an app is creating channels, then it likely will not need this
# section.
#
channels:
  # name of the channel
  chainhero:
    # Required. list of orderers designated by the application to use for transactions on this
    # channel. This list can be a result of access control ("org1" can only access "ordererA"), or
    # operational decisions to share loads from applications among the orderers.  The values must
    # be "names" of orgs defined under "organizations/peers"
    # deprecated: not recommended, to override any orderer configuration items, entity matchers should be used.
    # orderers:
    #  - orderer.example.com

    # Required. list of peers from participating orgs
    peers:
      peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io:
        # [Optional]. will this peer be sent transaction proposals for endorsement? The peer must
        # have the chaincode installed. The app can also use this property to decide which peers
        # to send the chaincode install request. Default: true
        endorsingPeer: true

        # [Optional]. will this peer be sent query proposals? The peer must have the chaincode
        # installed. The app can also use this property to decide which peers to send the
        # chaincode install request. Default: true
        chaincodeQuery: true

        # [Optional]. will this peer be sent query proposals that do not require chaincodes, like
        # queryBlock(), queryTransaction(), etc. Default: true
        ledgerQuery: true

        # [Optional]. will this peer be the target of the SDK's listener registration? All peers can
        # produce events but the app typically only needs to connect to one to listen to events.
        # Default: true
        eventSource: true

      peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io:

    policies:
      #[Optional] options for retrieving channel configuration blocks
      queryChannelConfig:
        #[Optional] min number of success responses (from targets/peers)
        minResponses: 1
        #[Optional] channel config will be retrieved for these number of random targets
        maxTargets: 1
        #[Optional] retry options for query config block
        retryOpts:
          #[Optional] number of retry attempts
          attempts: 5
          #[Optional] the back off interval for the first retry attempt
          initialBackoff: 500ms
          #[Optional] the maximum back off interval for any retry attempt
          maxBackoff: 5s
          #[Optional] he factor by which the initial back off period is exponentially incremented
          backoffFactor: 2.0


#
# list of participating organizations in this network
#
organizations:
  org1:
    mspid: org1.hf.chainhero.io
    cryptoPath: peerOrganizations/org1.hf.chainhero.io/users/{userName}@org1.hf.chainhero.io/msp
    peers:
      - peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io
      - peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io

    # [Optional]. Certificate Authorities issue certificates for identification purposes in a Fabric based
    # network. Typically certificates provisioning is done in a separate process outside of the
    # runtime network. Fabric-CA is a special certificate authority that provides a REST APIs for
    # dynamic certificate management (enroll, revoke, re-enroll). The following section is only for
    # Fabric-CA servers.
    certificateAuthorities:
      - ca.org1.hf.chainhero.io

#
# List of orderers to send transaction and channel create/update requests to. For the time
# being only one orderer is needed. If more than one is defined, which one get used by the
# SDK is implementation specific. Consult each SDK's documentation for its handling of orderers.
#
orderers:
  orderer.hf.chainhero.io:
    url: localhost:7050

    # these are standard properties defined by the gRPC library
    # they will be passed in as-is to gRPC client constructor
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer.hf.chainhero.io
      # These parameters should be set in coordination with the keepalive policy on the server,
      # as incompatible settings can result in closing of connection.
      # When duration of the 'keep-alive-time' is set to 0 or less the keep alive client parameters are disabled
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      # allow-insecure will be taken into consideration if address has no protocol defined, if true then grpc or else grpcs
      allow-insecure: false

    tlsCACerts:
      # Certificate location absolute path
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/chainHero/heroes-service/fixtures/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/hf.chainhero.io/tlsca/tlsca.hf.chainhero.io-cert.pem
#
# List of peers to send various requests to, including endorsement, query
# and event listener registration.
#
peers:
  peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io:
    # this URL is used to send endorsement and query requests
    url: localhost:7051
    # eventUrl is only needed when using eventhub (default is delivery service)
    eventUrl: localhost:7053

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io
      # These parameters should be set in coordination with the keepalive policy on the server,
      # as incompatible settings can result in closing of connection.
      # When duration of the 'keep-alive-time' is set to 0 or less the keep alive client parameters are disabled
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      # allow-insecure will be taken into consideration if address has no protocol defined, if true then grpc or else grpcs
      allow-insecure: false

    tlsCACerts:
      # Certificate location absolute path
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/chainHero/heroes-service/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.hf.chainhero.io/tlsca/tlsca.org1.hf.chainhero.io-cert.pem

  peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io:
    # this URL is used to send endorsement and query requests
    url: localhost:8051
    # eventUrl is only needed when using eventhub (default is delivery service)
    eventUrl: localhost:8053

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io
      # These parameters should be set in coordination with the keepalive policy on the server,
      # as incompatible settings can result in closing of connection.
      # When duration of the 'keep-alive-time' is set to 0 or less the keep alive client parameters are disabled
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      # allow-insecure will be taken into consideration if address has no protocol defined, if true then grpc or else grpcs
      allow-insecure: false

    tlsCACerts:
      # Certificate location absolute path
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/chainHero/heroes-service/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.hf.chainhero.io/tlsca/tlsca.org1.hf.chainhero.io-cert.pem

#
# Fabric-CA is a special kind of Certificate Authority provided by Hyperledger Fabric which allows
# certificate management to be done via REST APIs. Application may choose to use a standard
# Certificate Authority instead of Fabric-CA, in which case this section would not be specified.
#
certificateAuthorities:
  ca.org1.hf.chainhero.io:
    url: http://localhost:7054
    # Fabric-CA supports dynamic user enrollment via REST APIs. A "root" user, a.k.a registrar, is
    # needed to enroll and invoke new users.
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    registrar:
      enrollId: admin
      enrollSecret: adminpw
    # [Optional] The optional name of the CA.
    caName: ca.org1.hf.chainhero.io
    tlsCACerts:
      # Certificate location absolute path
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/chainHero/heroes-service/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.hf.chainhero.io/ca/ca.org1.hf.chainhero.io-cert.pem

entityMatchers:
  peer:
    - pattern: (\w*)peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7051
      eventUrlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7053
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io
      mappedHost: peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io

    - pattern: (\w*)peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:8051
      eventUrlSubstitutionExp: localhost:8053
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io
      mappedHost: peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io

  orderer:
    - pattern: (\w*)orderer.hf.chainhero.io(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7050
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: orderer.hf.chainhero.io
      mappedHost: orderer.hf.chainhero.io

  certificateAuthorities:
    - pattern: (\w*)ca.org1.hf.chainhero.io(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: http://localhost:7054
      mappedHost: ca.org1.hf.chainhero.io
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2'

networks:
  default:

services:

  orderer.hf.chainhero.io:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0
    container_name: orderer.hf.chainhero.io
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISPROFILE=ChainHero
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=hf.chainhero.io
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-1.1.0
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - ./artifacts/orderer.genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/hf.chainhero.io/orderers/orderer.hf.chainhero.io/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/hf.chainhero.io/orderers/orderer.hf.chainhero.io/tls:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - orderer.hf.chainhero.io

  ca.org1.hf.chainhero.io:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0
    container_name: ca.org1.hf.chainhero.io
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org1.hf.chainhero.io
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.hf.chainhero.io-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/5da5c8049a9ec349ec4447c82a9c0f7db75b84012a78954ef083a9c9e4a9fa25_sk
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.hf.chainhero.io-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/5da5c8049a9ec349ec4447c82a9c0f7db75b84012a78954ef083a9c9e4a9fa25_sk
    ports:
      - 7054:7054
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.hf.chainhero.io/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - ca.org1.hf.chainhero.io

  peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0
    container_name: peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_ATTACHSTDOUT=true
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=chainhero
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/var/hyperledger/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_SKIPHANDSHAKE=true
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=org1.hf.chainhero.io
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/var/hyperledger/msp
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_SERVERHOSTOVERRIDE=peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.hf.chainhero.io/peers/peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io/msp:/var/hyperledger/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.hf.chainhero.io/peers/peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io/tls:/var/hyperledger/tls
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    depends_on:
      - orderer.hf.chainhero.io
    links:
      - orderer.hf.chainhero.io
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io

  peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0
    container_name: peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_ATTACHSTDOUT=true
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=chainhero
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/var/hyperledger/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_SKIPHANDSHAKE=true
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=org1.hf.chainhero.io
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/var/hyperledger/msp
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_SERVERHOSTOVERRIDE=peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.hf.chainhero.io/peers/peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io/msp:/var/hyperledger/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.hf.chainhero.io/peers/peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io/tls:/var/hyperledger/tls
    ports:
      - 8051:7051
      - 8053:7053
    depends_on:
      - orderer.hf.chainhero.io
    links:
      - orderer.hf.chainhero.io
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io
```

docker-compose-couch.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

services:
  couchdb0:
    container_name: couchdb0
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"

  peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io:
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0:7051
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb0

  couchdb1:
    container_name: couchdb1
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "6984:5984"

  peer1.org1.hf.chainhero.io:
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb1:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb1

  couchdb2:
    container_name: couchdb2
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "7984:5984"

  # peer0.org2.example.com:
  #   environment:
  #     - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
  #     - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb2:5984
  #     - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
  #     - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
  #   depends_on:
  #     - couchdb2
  #
  # couchdb3:
  #   container_name: couchdb3
  #   image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
  #   environment:
  #     - COUCHDB_USER=
  #     - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
  #   # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
  #   # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
  #   ports:
  #     - "8984:5984"
  #
  # peer1.org2.example.com:
  #   environment:
  #     - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
  #     - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb3:5984
  #     - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
  #     - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
  #   depends_on:
  #     - couchdb3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As assummed it was a problem with the ports in the compose-docker-douch.yaml, were I needed to change:

`peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io:
...
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0:7051`

to

`peer0.org1.hf.chainhero.io:
...
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0:5984`